# Postfix sends using TLS but no info in Delivery Notice (DSN) mail

Tags: ssl, postfix, dsn

I got a postfix server runnig with DKIM and TLS for SMTP and SMPTD also configured.
When I send a test mail to my gmail account it always states `Standard-Encryption TLS` which is fine. Also the headers tell `Received: ... (version=TLS1_2) ...`.

The weird thing is, that there seems to be no hint in the Delivery Notice Mail about using TLS successfully.

1. Can somebody help me understanding where that information is held in the report mail or how to configure the DSN to show clearly that TLS was used?
2. Any Ideas for alternatives, if that is impossible? I need a receipt to proof the mail was sent using TLS in whatever way.

The DN just reads like this:

````
Your message was successfully delivered to the destination(s)
listed below. If the message was delivered to mailbox you will
receive no further notifications. Otherwise you may still receive
notifications of mail delivery errors from other systems.

                   The mail system

<xxx>: delivery via spamassassin: delivered via spamassassin
    service
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxx
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: DD1BD7F427
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; xxx
Arrival-Date: Thu,  1 Feb 2024 10:28:35 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxx
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxx
Action: relayed
Status: 2.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; delivery via spamassassin: delivered via
    spamassassin service
Return-Path: <xxx>
Received: from xxx (xxx [xxx])
    by xxx (Postfix) with ESMTP id DD1BD7F427
    for <xxx>; Thu,  1 Feb 2024 10:28:35 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=xxx; s=mail;
    t=1706779715; bh=xxx;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References:From;
    b=xxx
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 01 Feb 2024 10:28:35 +0100
From: xxx <xxx>
To: xxx
Subject: Re: test 1234556
In-Reply-To: <36319b40fad3fbe0b9c34995e342fea8@xxx>
References: ...
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail
Message-ID: <9811edce17dc01e4ce43a435b0c1ebf2@xxx>
X-Sender: xxx
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="=_72c61e5e13394bd306b6254a28f27cfb"```
````

Comment: Are you certain you need unencrypted delivery, *at all*? These days, depending on what sort of traffic you send, you could possibly get away with pointing to regulatory compliance and fall back to only the two cases a) "not delivered, failed to establish TLS" and b) "delivered, and *of course* the channel was protected according to current best practices"

Comment: @anx I wouldn't recommend that as it breaks backwards compatibility with the systems that don't support TLS. It is possible to enforce TLS for domains known to support it using DANE, MTA-STS (requires configuration on both ends) and [`smtp_tls_policy_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps).

Comment: Have you include this https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_received_header

Comment: @Turdie the `smtpd_tls_received_header` parameter modifies the `Received:` header on the inbound connection, but this question asks about the template documenting the following, *outgoing* transmission.